# J2EE/JPA: Controlling Transaction Isolation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, transactions, glassfish

I would like to use different transaction isolation levels for the same Persistence Context in an J2EE environment. For example:

```
UserTransaction ut=...;
EntityManagerFactory emf=...;
EntityManager em=emf.createEntityManager;

ut.begin();
em.joinTransaction(); => use RepeatableRead isolation here
...
ut.commit();

ut.begin();
em.joinTransaction(); => use Serializable isolation here
...
ut.commit();
```

I've found no way to achieve that. When the EM first acquires the DB connection, it is taken from the pool and immediately enlisted with the current XA transaction. Afterwards it is not possible anymore to change the transaction isolation of that DB Transaction.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Here's some interesting info for you : http://amitstechblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/supporting-custom-isolation-levels-with-jpa/

Comment: @Pat B: thanks for the link. The blog discusses a Hibernate/Spring solution. As far as I can see, it can not be used in a JTA environment (like J2EE), since the transaction gets started by the Datasource implementation, not by the JPA provider itself.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Glassfish/EclipseLink/MySQL. The solution I found was to customize the MySQL DataSource to return a wrapper around the XAResource which sets the transaction isolation before starting the XA transaction. That way, the desired transaction isolation can be set before starting a transaction.

```
public class CustomDataSource extends MysqlXADataSource {

private static ThreadLocal<Integer> isolation=new ThreadLocal<Integer>(){
    protected Integer initialValue() {
        return Connection.TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ;
    };
};

public static void setTransactionIsolation(int i){
    isolation.set(i);
}

private static class XAConnectionWrapper implements XAConnection {

    private XAConnection delegate;

    public XAConnectionWrapper(XAConnection delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    ... delegate methods

    @Override
    public XAResource getXAResource() throws SQLException {
        return new XAResourceWrapper(delegate.getXAResource());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return delegate.equals(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return delegate.hashCode();
    }
}

private static class XAResourceWrapper implements XAResource {
    private XAResource delegate;
    private Field field;

    ... delegate methods ...

    public void start(Xid xid, int flags) throws XAException {
        try {
            ConnectionImpl connection = (ConnectionImpl) field
                    .get(delegate);
            connection
                    .setTransactionIsolation(isolation.get());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException
                | SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        delegate.start(xid, flags);
    }

    public XAResourceWrapper(XAResource delegate) {
        try {
            field = MysqlXAConnection.class
                    .getDeclaredField("underlyingConnection");
            field.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return delegate.equals(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return delegate.hashCode();
    }
}

@Override
public XAConnection getXAConnection() throws SQLException {
    XAConnection conn = super.getXAConnection();

    return new XAConnectionWrapper(conn);
}

@Override
public XAConnection getXAConnection(String u, String p) throws SQLException {
    return new XAConnectionWrapper(super.getXAConnection(u, p));
}
}
```